# How to load a ruby script in IRB?

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, notepad++, command-prompt, irb

I typed a ruby script in Notepad++, and got the output in command-prompt. But when I tried to load the script using the command- **load "route.rb"** in IRB, it flashed the below error.

My Scripts are located in C:/Ruby21-x64/Ruby

```
Cannot load such file-- route.rb
from (irb):4:in 'load'
from (irb):4
from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/irb:11:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Just a sanity check: are you in the same directory when starting up `irb`?

Comment: @Drenmi I didn't get you. I am a complete novice to ruby.

Comment: When you run `irb` from your command line, are you in that (C:/Ruby21-x64/Ruby) directory? :-) The `load` command will look for the file relative to the current working directory. You can check in `irb` by typing `Dir.pwd`.

Comment: @Drenmi Got the output! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to cd into the directory where your module resides. Otherwise the module you are trying to load will be unavailable to the irb session.

Comment: I found out that there was no 'route.rb' file in the bin directory. So, I tired to move the file to the bin directory. And it worked like a charm ;). Now i am able to see outputs in both command-prompt and IRB. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: So you weren't in the right directory as I assumed. No problem :)